# Prove: if $c^2+8 \equiv 0$ mod $p$ then $c^3-7c^2-8c$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to show:

> If $c^2+8 \equiv 0$ mod $p$ for prime $p>3$, then $c^3-7c^2-8c$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

I have calculated that $c^3-7c^2-8c \equiv -7c^2-16c \equiv 56- 16c \equiv 8(7-2c) \equiv c^2 (2c -7)$, so it should be enough to see that $2c -7$ is a quadratic residue. What now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2c-7\equiv2c-7+c^2+8\pmod p\equiv(c+1)^2$$

Comment: @AJ. Have you noticed my other answer. That is much more natural derivation

Answer (score 3):

We have that 
$$(c +1)^2 = c^2 + 2c + 1 = c^2 + 2c + 8 -7 = (c^2 + 8) + (2c - 7) \equiv 2c - 7 \mod p.$$
This proves the claim.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

As $c^2\equiv-8\pmod p,$

$$c(c+1)=c^2+c\equiv c-8\pmod p$$

$c(c+1)(c-8)\equiv?$

I believe this is how the problem naturally came into being .

Comment: Not sure about any mistake which has caused the down-vote ! This has been put in a separate post as the approach in the other markedly different.

Comment: Me neither... $(+1)$